# Why is dig query time slower on one computer vs another in the same LAN?

Tags: networking, performance, dig

To make a long story short, I setup DNS forwarding/caching using dnsmasq built into my router (EdgeRouter).

My test command is simple:

```
dig www.example.com
```

On one computer, which happens to be a 2016 MacBook 1.3 GHz Core m7, I consistently get a query time reported by dig of around 60-70ms. On another computer (a 2016 iMac 4 GHz Core i7), on the same WAP, network, etc., I consistently get 1-2ms. All of the options, flags, etc. and the actual return values are the same on both.

The only thing I can figure is that it's just the speed of the computer itself that is making up this difference, but somehow that seems wrong. Seems like dig should account for that, but maybe it can't. Is it CPU speed or should I be looking at something else?

I used namebench, and it seems right (like 4-5ms avg). I'm just perplexed why dig reports so high on this laptop.

Comment: Does something like wireshark show any differences in when the packets get back?

Comment: Could it be the faster one is caching it?

Comment: @thrig, interesting. I see the query and response on both in wireshark. On the iMac it's 2.3ms (while dig reports 2ms); on the MacBook it's 3.8ms (while dig reports 97ms).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I don't think that's what's going on here. My understanding is dig should not rely on local cache and should always ask the dns resolver. It seems like wireshark confirms that, too, as noted in my last comment. I am sure the router's dnsmasq instance is caching it, given the response time.

Comment: Is `dig` the same on both? Or for an alternative take can you install `dig` via fink|macports|homebrew and see how fast that is on the MacBook? (e.g. with macports `sudo port install bind9` then use `/opt/local/bin/dig`)

Comment: @thrig, yup, so that version of dig reports the expected time (~3ms on average). Any ideas on why that might be happening on this MacBook but not the iMac?

Comment: I guess it would be break-out-dtrace time and try to figure out where `dig` is spending that extra time.

Comment: Another interesting observation is that if I use +tcp, it returns in the expected time (~3-4ms). But if I use the default or +notcp, it is the longer time, as if something wonky is going on with UDP.  But doing the same on the macports version consistently reports 3-4ms. I guess I need to figure out dtrace. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is because you are using different name servers.

Usually every domain (or zone) has several name servers, and programs choose one random.

You could do a

`dig example.com`

to find the name servers, and choose one.

`dig @ns1.registrar.example www.example.com`

Only in this case you can really do a comparable test between machines. Note: this method also remove the lookup caches.
Maybe you will still have the speed difference, but now you are comparing the same query.

Comment: BTW reading the number, I assume that the slow machine has the primary resolved down, so after a timeout, it will try the second one.

Comment: I confirmed both are asking and getting a response from the same server. I've tried both my local DNS server and 8.8.8.8. Both reflect similar discrepancies in response times between the two. In the comments on the original question, I also reported tracing with Wireshark and saw that the actual network query itself appeared to be comparably fast. I do not believe this is a network issue but something on the MacBook itself that is slowing dig down.